# Is it possible to overbrush a cat?

Tags: cats

I am taking care of an elderly Maine Coon who can't really groom himself well. He enjoys being brushed and he changes his lying position to indicate where he wants to get brushed.

In my experience, cats doesn't like brushing much so I brush them as long as they let me. However, this cat never resists being brushed, unless it is back of his hind legs. I can brush him every day he will be happy with it.

Is it possible for me to overbrush him?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, yes, it is possible to overbrush cats, though it also depends on what kind of brush you are using. The Furminator, for example, actually tends to pull out hair (which mind you doesn't hurt cats like it does humans), but it can actually thin out a cat's fur if used too much. If you use a more regular kind of brush that doesn't happen so much, and so it's probably fine to use on a regular basis. If you're really concerned, try to make sure you don't brush one area over and over, and keep an eye on your cat's fur.

Answer (score 2):

Not every cat hates brushing, even my cat loves it. It simply lies down and feels so comfortable and happy in that process.

It's all okay with your cat. But you can simply switch his attention or mood when you have brushed it properly once. You can use some toy or feather to switch his attention. Because now, it is loving it. But once its habitual to this, then it will come wherever you are and will simply lie down or sit with you for that. Possibly it stops sleeping except that. Because it will learn that, its all Okay with that.

And at that time, if you are busy or not giving it complete time as you are doing now, then it will be upset.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Could you specify what constitutes one proper brushing? I think the OP is asking at what point it becomes over-brushed?

Comment: If you are brushing your cat two times properly in day, then still it is normal. But more than that can be said over brushing. But it can also depend on the routine of cat. Some cats are going outside, and need more brushing. While some are at home, and don't need much. And from properly brush I mean that you are brushing all main areas of cat at least once, instead of brushing only single part again and again! Because over brushing can also harm your cat's fur.